# how to sync firebase and local data model in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

Pretty positive I'm just totally overthinking this or approaching it from an illogical angle.

I'm separating my logic from my ui where button presses call a method located in the userModel which has a change notifier (getting passed into MyApp with a provider). I'm trying to implement firebase but have never called firebase directly from the ui (always just had the requests in the ui code, never used a model).

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tuple/tuple.dart';
//TODO: firebase has been installed now I need to figure out how to implement it

// TODO: add firebase read and write

class UserModel with ChangeNotifier {
  //index = session number
  List session = [];
  //create an instance of firebase (this might need to go higher in the tree)
  var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  //TODO:
  //convert incoming firebase to JSON
  //convert outgoing json to firebase
  //track session

  // takes in current session data and adds the new chunk
  // already recorded (new item in list but time, breaks etc. are adding from the last one)
  // IF ADDING TO EXISTING, ALL PARAMETRS MUST BE SET

  addSessionChunk(
      {required String intention,
      int workTime = 0,
      String progress = "null",
      int breakTime = 0}) {
    session.add({
      "intention": intention,
      "workTime": workTime,
      "progress": progress,
      "breakTime": breakTime,
    });
    //firebase update?
  }

  //TODO: when returning to a previous intention, add to the numbers that were
  //TODO: currently only works for 1 call per chunk (no going back to the same intention)
  //get previous data from this intention for returning to a task (do

  //these update functions updadate the LAST CHUNK in the session

  updateChunkWorkTime({required int workTime}) {
    //this later)
    session.last["workTime"] = workTime;
  }

  //takes in inputed progress and updates the latest chunk with it
  updateChunkProgress({required String progress}) {
    session.last["progress"] = progress;
  }

  //takes inputed breaktime and updates the lastest chunk with it
  updateChunkBreakTime({required int breakTime}) {
    session.last["breakTime"] = breakTime;
  }

  //returns tuple of the total time spent working and breaking in the current session

  calculateSessionTimeTotal() {
    int totalWorkTime = 0;
    int totalBreakTime = 0;

    for (var chunk in session) {
      totalWorkTime += chunk["workTime"] as int;
      totalBreakTime += chunk["breakTime"] as int;
    }

    return Tuple2(totalWorkTime, totalBreakTime);
  }

  //firebase functions
  pushDataUp() {
    db.collection("sessions").doc().set({
      "currentSession": session,
      "total": calculateSessionTimeTotal().toString()
    });
  }

  pullDataDown() {}
}
```

You can see at the bottom there I started to try and come up with a way to sync the local data state with firebase but am confused. Seems weird for the user to send their data up to firebase then back down into the model which is already holding that data?

Whats the best approach to local model and cloud database interaction? Any guidance in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What seems weird to you, is actually a quite well defined patterns known as [command query responsibility segregation](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html), and is the basic pattern behind most modern UI frameworks. By separating the command (the writing of the data here) from the query (the reading of the data here) each remains simpler, and the total app becomes much easier to reason about.

With Firestore in Flutter, this usually translates into:

1. The user takes some action.
2. Your code writes to the database.
3. Your `onSnapshot` listener gets triggered with the updated data.
4. Your code updates the data model/state with the new data.
5. Which then renders the updated UI.

All of this happens pretty instantly, as Firebase actually handles it locally before even sending the data to the server and handles any exception that may occur during the synchronization with the server.